# How to detect homophone

Tags: nlp, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I am fairly new to speech processing, but wondering how [homophones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym) are detected. I am in search for an API which gives similarity between two words on the basis of how they are pronounced.

**for example:** "to" and "two" are highly similar in terms of how they sound with respect to say "to" and "from".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do speech recognition algorithms recognize homophones?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684594/how-do-speech-recognition-algorithms-recognize-homophones)

Comment: Circular reference ftw! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684594/how-do-speech-recognition-algorithms-recognize-homophones#comment40962774_14699770

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try calculating the edit distance not on the original strings, but on pronunciations, like they are available in the CMU Pronouncing Dictionary at http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict

Answer (score 1):

The following are used for indexing words by their English pronunciation [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) or [Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone). You can use python packages like [Fuzzy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fuzzy) that implement several indexing algorithms.

```
import fuzzy
```