# How to compare two homophones using simple function

Tags: python, string, function, performance, comparison

#program of comparing two string names
def main():

```
n_1=input()

n_2=input()

i=0

ch=0

for i in n_1:
 
 if(i in n_2):
 
 if n_1.lower()==n_2.lower():
    ch=0

if(ch==0):
 print("match")
else:
 print("not match")
```

main()

Image description
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgCVz.jpg

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: We have to print match on comparison of two strings sounding same but spelled differently

Comment: Is your problem an error in the code or is it your basic algorithm doesn't work?  It seems more complex than your algorithm.  Check out [How to detect homophone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134036/how-to-detect-homophone)